# Terraform: The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data" blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

i'm new to terraform and I have difficulty in using module in terraform.

I have a subnet resource in `modules` directory following like this.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "this" {
    count = var.subnet_cidr_block_count
    cidr_block = var.subnet_cidr_blocks
    vpc_id = var.vpc_id
    availability_zone = var.aws_az
}
```

and I was trying to call the module like this.

```
module "public-subnet" {
  source = "../modules/subnet"

  subnet_cidr_block_count = "${length(var.cidr_blocks)}"
  subnet_cidr_blocks = "${element(var.cidr_blocks, count.index)}"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.id
  aws_az = "${element(var.aws_az, count.index)}"
}
```

but terraform returned this error

```
The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data" blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.
```

I guess that there would be something wrong in my module definition. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What is the FULL error message, showing exact line when it occurs. Also what version of TF do you use.

Comment: @Marcin 
I'm using 1.3.7 version. and the full error message is `Reference to "count" in non-counted context: 14:   subnet_cidr_blocks = "${element(var.cidr_blocks, count.index)}"

The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data" blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.`

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen when you write `${element(var.cidr_blocks, count.index)}`?

Comment: @Marcin what I expected is to get the element located in specified index of list.

Comment: Only one index? If so, which one? Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't set the `count` meta-argument in the module call, i.e., there is no `count` set here:

```
module "public-subnet" {
  source = "../modules/subnet"

  subnet_cidr_block_count = "${length(var.cidr_blocks)}"
  subnet_cidr_blocks = "${element(var.cidr_blocks, count.index)}"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.id
  aws_az = "${element(var.aws_az, count.index)}"
}
```

That further means you cannot use `count.index` object as it does not have anything to refer to. If the `aws_az` was using the same variables as the `subnet_cidr_block_count` and `subnet_cidr_blocks` variables, the code could be fixed. So you either have to find a common variable to use `count` meta-argument with, or you have to rethink how you are passing the variable values to the module.

EDIT: Looking at the code again, I guess you could move the logic into the module. For example:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "this" {
    count      = var.subnet_cidr_block_count

    cidr_block        = element(var.cidr_blocks, count.index)
    vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
    availability_zone = element(var.aws_az, count.index)
}
```

The module call would then look like this:

```
module "public-subnet" {
  source = "../modules/subnet"

  subnet_cidr_block_count = length(var.cidr_blocks)
  subnet_cidr_blocks      = var.cidr_blocks
  vpc_id                  = module.vpc.id
  aws_az                  = var.aws_az
}
```

Comment: Haven't you forgotten about `count = length(var.cidr_blocks)`?

Comment: But that's in the module code right? Not in the module call? How would he pass the variable value using `count.index` if the module is not instantiated with `count`?  I edited the question with how I would refactor that part of the code, maybe that will provide the explanation necessary to understand my train of thought.

Comment: That's why I'm confused about the question and answer. Because i'm not sure of `module.public-subnet` should create only one subnet, or all subnets?

Comment: Haha, I hope I understood what the question is, but I'm more than happy to retract my answer if that's not what the OP is asking. I did a lot of "reading between the lines of code". :)